# Webpart to show documents, it's folders and underlying files

Tags: document-library, filter

I have few document libraries with lot of folders and files in it.

The Out of box webpart shows in sequential way and every click does a page refresh (sometimes users get lost of focus when it refreshes).

I am thinking of writing custom code for this.

Any recommendations? I am sure people must have done this. If there are any working examples or links, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can create list views to show all items without folders for easier viewing of files.  However you'll want to make sure you page and filter the view.  No need to recreate the wheel.

When you create a list view, scroll down to the bottom options and you'll see a collapsed heading called Fodlers.  Expand that and select Show all items without folders.

Comment: I need to show with folders as the folders have meaning to users. So I need folders to be displayed.

Comment: Then I'm confused with your request, why do you need to create a new web part when the default list views handle that already?  If users are getting lost, they can click back in the browser or use the breadcrumb bar.

Comment: Meaning that you can add the library to any web part page with whatever view you'd like.

Comment: The page that shows this webpart (of document library) has lot of other information from other webparts. So assume this webpart is the center of the page and user clicks on a particular foldername, the page gets reloaded but they loose the focus of where the control went. Hope I am making things clear.

Comment: In that case, you might want to put the document library on the page via a page viewer webpart and it'll act like an iframe and should mitigate the full page refresh I believe.